# using loopback for testing environment

Tags: java, tcp, ip, loopback

I want to run two instance of same server on same physical machine. These two servers will listen to same port, say 12345. I am trying run one server on 127.0.0.1, and the other one on 127.0.0.2. These two servers will basically send and receive messages using same port but running on separate loopback addresses. I do not know if I am on correct path to set this test environment? Somehow, I am not able to setting this testing environment. I am using java to develop the server.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to bind the two servers to the same port. Why do you want to do that ?

Comment: I need this mechanism for testing environment. Otherwise I need to upload the program to the physical machines every time I want to try. This will so much time consuming. There is a mechanism called loopback. I do not know if it allows to use same port for multiple loopback addresses.

Comment: @lmsteffan Not so, see my answer.

Comment: @EJP I stand corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind two servers to the same port if you specify two different interfaces:

```
ServerSocket s1 = new ServerSocket(port, 500, InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"));
ServerSocket s2 = new ServerSocket(port, 500, InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.2"));
```

Comment: So the question is can these two servers communicate each other using same port on loopback? This is my main question. I actually test them, and you are right. I am able to run two servers on loopback, but they cannot communicate using same port. Send from 127.0.0.1:12345 to 127.0.0.2:12345. This did not work.

Comment: @celik Of course they can, if they use the correct IP:port to connect to each other. I don't understand the last part. 127.0.0.1 is a *listening* port, and indicates a listening socket. You can't send anything with it anywhere. Why would you want to?

Comment: Make sure loopback ip addresses are active. For Mac osx, they are passive. If you ping 127.0.0.2, you will see timeouts. To activate them, run ifconfig lo0 alias 127.0.0.2

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly what my fork of [NanoHTTPD](http://elonen.iki.fi/code/nanohttpd/) was intended for:

https://github.com/gitgrimbo/nanohttpd/commit/9535d1b6b4c1bbc927d390327018882d84df959f

```
Added ability to specify hostname to bind to.

For example:

java NanoHTTPD -d wwwroot1 -h 127.0.0.1
java NanoHTTPD -d wwwroot2 -h 127.0.0.2
java NanoHTTPD -d wwwroot3 -h 127.0.0.3

And hosts file:

127.0.0.1   www1.example.com
127.0.0.2   www2.example.com
127.0.0.3   www3.example.com
```

Specifically line 225 (in the commit link above):

```
myServerSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(hostname, port));
```

This code, combined with my instructions above, show how you can run a server on several loopback addresses, all using the same port (80 by default, but could be any of your choice).

Comment: Sorry, I havent checked your program. Is it an example of using such mechanism?

Comment: Doesn't actually answer the question. A 'yes' or 'no' would answer it, not a link to an entire project.

Comment: I respectfully disagree. My answer may not be as simple an answer as yours, but it certainly could be more useful in the long run as a 'real world' example.

Comment: I don't see that. He is already developing his server. All he needs to know is that it is possible.